# Rendering problem with the OpenGL GL_POINTS primitive

Tags: opengl

When using software rendering, or any graphics card in our developlment office, our little coloured GL_POINTS render in exactly the colour we expect.  Out in the field, some users report points rendered in the wrong colours.  Getting them to turn off hardware acceleration fixed their problem, so we've been putting the whole thing down to a third-party issue and using a workaround (tiny pixel-sized rectangles whose colour remains unproblematic). The snag: we are taking a huge performance hit.

My question is, has anyone else had a similar issue, and, if so, did they come up with a way to keep their GL_POINTS *and* get the colour right?

Comment: Are you using a color palette (indexed colors) or RGBA? Can you reproduce the bug in a tiny bit of code? Is glPointSize = 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered similar problem, but the solution is simple : get the card your user is using, and set the same environment.

Maybe the problem is something stupid as old drivers. I don't see what else can render wrong color.

Comment: I thought the same, especially given that software rendering fixed the problem.  Unfortunately, our users can't/won't update the drivers.

Comment: @Edward In that case, get the same GPU chips and similar environment, and find a work around.